# Как посмотреть информацию о запущенных процессах на Ubuntu, не используя ps, через каталог proc?

Tags: linux

Как посмотреть информацию о запущенных процессах на Ubuntu, не используя *ps*, через каталог ***proc*** через терминал? Я не совсем понимаю

Comment: всё верно написали: через каталог `/proc`. а в чём вопрос-то? уточните, нажав [edit]

Comment: Отредактировал. Я не понимаю, как именно получить информацию о запущенных процессах из каталога proc через терминал

Comment: [просмотреть содержимое каталога, как обычно — программой `ls`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=ls&category=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd /proc/

for pid in [0-9]*
do
  printf "\n${pid}\t"
  cat $pid/cmdline
done

popd
```